# Colour fill nav items based on div position

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollmagic

I have 10 nav items in the left column (Section 1-10) which relate to 10 div sections in the right hand column.

What I want to do is full up each nav items background colour (left to right with colour) based on how far I am through each section.

So I am halfway through section 1, it's filled 50%. Once I scroll to section 2 that nav item starts filling up etc.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out all day using a combination of ScrollMagic and just general jQuery scroll offset, but I can't get it to work on a per div scroll basis. I can trigger a class on the nav items based on scroll but that fills up the whole bar for example.when I need it to fill up based on how high the section div has been scrolled through.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the scrollTop() JQuery method to the height of a specific section, then you can determine how far it is through one:

```
var percentage = $("nav").scrollTop() / $("#section1").height() * 100;
```

For each subsequent section, it will need to compare the [scroll MINUS the height of all previous sections] to the height of the current section.

Comment: Ahh so that's kind of working, but say my nav li is 209px wide. How would I apply that percentage of read through to the background (pixel position) of my nav item?  `background: linear-gradient(to right, #A1C866 49%,#A1C866 49%,#EDEDED 49%); for example?`

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would minus or do each subsequent section? I can't seem to figure out how to subtract and get the correct value for any other sections.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...so you're using the gradient as a progress indicator? Once you get the percentage using the calculation I mentioned, you can then use that percentage for the first color, but then you don't need to specify the second color's percentage, as it just takes up the rest...like so:

```
$("nav").css({"background": "linear-gradient(to right, #A1C866 " + percentage + "%, #EDEDED)"});
```

Then it just shows an indicator of how far through the current section the user has scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Also, getting the height of each section is easiest by means of giving them all IDs (like in my example, section1, section2, etc)...then you can get each height using jquery:

```
$("#section1").height() + $("#section2").height() ...
```

you can even use a loop to go through them until it surpasses the current scrollTop, then you'll know which one is currently being viewed.